# Docker compose phpmyadmin fails login

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following in my docker-compose.yaml

```
 db:
  image: mysql:5.7.22
  container_name: db
  restart: unless-stopped
  tty: true
  ports:
   - "3306:3306"
  environment:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: pos
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 5378
    SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    SERVICE_NAME: mysql
  volumes:
  - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
  - ./dockerconfig/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
  networks:
  - app-network

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: pepo_phpmyadmin
    ports:
    - 8000:80
    environment:
    - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
    - PMA_HOST=pepo_mysql
    depends_on:
    - db
    restart: always

#Docker Networks
networks:
 app-network:
driver: bridge
```

SO when i access localhost:800 am getting the phpmyadminlogin page as shown below

[image]

I have tried using the following credentials

```
server:db
username:root
password:5378
```

But it always fails with an error `mysqli_real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known` 
I have tried changing server field from db to phpmyadmin but am getting an error `mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused`

What do i need to use for the credentials
What am i missing out?

Addition for the php section

```
webserver:
 image: nginx
 container_name: webserver
 restart: unless-stopped
 tty: true
 ports:
 - "80:80"
 - "443:443"
 volumes:
  - ./:/var/www
  - ./dockerconfig/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
networks:
- app-network
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add the network to your php :

```
 phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: pepo_phpmyadmin
    ports:
     - 8000:80
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
      - PMA_HOST=db
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
    networks:
      - app-network
```

then put `db` in server field

and change the `PMA_HOST=pepo_mysql` to `PMA_HOST=db`

Comment: I have updated the question with my php section, even by using  db in server field it still fails to login

Comment: did you add `networks: - app-network` to your `phpmyadmin` service ?

Comment: I see thanks i needed to change the PMA_HOST=pepo_mysql to PMA_HOST=db

Comment: Yes the network part is also added, update your answer with the environment part so that i can mark it to help another person

Comment: I added your environment part

Comment: It will also work to delete all of the `networks:` blocks in the whole file; Docker Compose creates a default network for you.  (In the question, the `db` container is on the `app-network` network and `phpmyadmin` on the `default` network, which is why they don't connect.)